# Where did you end up? [Part 1]

Tags: logical-deduction, treasure-hunt

Follow the clues and tell me where you are in the end.

> 1. PSE
> 2. To the opposite of the opposite of 2 + 2 ~= 4
> 3. Go to the way you round .5
> 4. If up is down and down is up go down
> 5. You're on the right track
> 6. You've made it, where are you?

**This is part 1. I may not make a part 2, but others in the community may.**

Comment: Uh... well, the opposite of the opposite of something is ostensibly itself.

Comment: @generalcrispy Are you sure?

Comment: No. Yes. No. Yes. No.

Comment: Heh general, whatever you say. Lets guide you to the conclusion what is 2 + 2 ~= 4, what's the opposite of that? What's the opposite of that?

Comment: "~=", in most instances, means "is not equal to". I usually use "!=". The opposite, obviously, is "2 + 2 = 4". Opposite again takes you back to the same thing.

Comment: @general I wanna type that clue out so badly... 2 + 2 ~= 4 is obviously what word?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18605/discussion-between-generalcrispy-and-warspyking).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. PSE very likely stands for **p**uzzles.**s**tack**e**xchange, hence I'm starting right here.
2. The statement `2 + 2 ≠ 4` is *wrong*. The opposite of wrong is *right*. The opposite of right is *left*.
3. .5 is rounded *up* (usually, on pen and paper).
4. Up (proper) is down (1), and down (1) is up (2). Ergo up (2) is up (proper), and we can deduce that down (2) is therefore down (proper). Hence by going down (2), I go *down*.
5. You're on the *right* track.
6. I've gone up, down, right, and left, thus I'm right back where I started: on puzzles.stackexchange! :D

Comment: Good job! This is actually the correct answer. What was the hardest clue?

Comment: @warspyking: I looked up PSE as an acronym and got nothing, but then the SE stood out as "StackExchange" in my mind. And my answer to (4) was originally "up" since I interpreted the clue as "up (proper) is down (1), and down (proper) is up (1), ergo down (1) is up", but "two units up from puzzles.SE" seemed like a dumb answer, so I fell back to the puzzler's trump card: creatively reinterpret clues until they give you the answer you want. :D

Comment: Hmmm interesting I think I'm gonna make another one of these.