# Where did you end up? [Part 2!]

Tags: lateral-thinking, treasure-hunt

Follow the clues and tell me where you are in the end.

> 1. You are here
> 2. The birthplace
> 3. The biggest child
> 4. The first letter of it's name
> 5. Go left

*Note: This one is harder, and has the requirement that you have to live in US/Canada or assume that you do.*

**Hint:**

> You need to make the Canada/US for clue #5

**This is part 2 of a series of puzzles, part 1 can be found here: [Where did you end up? [Part 1]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/where-did-you-end-up-part-1) feel free to join in the fun!**

Comment: Do we actually need any specific US/Canada knowledge, or is it just something to generic and common-knowledge that everyone ought to know?

Comment: @Joe Well it's not specific, if you live in US/Canada and some other places it's common knowledge. If you don't know and you figure out the clue it'll only take 1 google search to get the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are here:

> Puzzling.SE

The Birthplace:

> Area 51

The Biggest Child:

> Graphic Design

The First Letter of it's Name:

> G

Go Left:

> F

Comment: Good job! Which was the hardest clue?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to do any better than this

You are here:

> 1. North America

The birthplace:

> Jamestown, VA

Biggest Child

> Georgia is the largest of the thirteen colonies

To the left

> Alabama

Comment: Nope. Good try though I must say!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but...

You are here

> PSE

The birthplace

> StackExchange

The biggest child

> StackOverflow

The first letter of it's name

> S

Go left

> R? Meaning Rhode Island? Because it's the

Comment: I would agree with all before Go left.  My answer would be U, based on the hint, as left of S in US.  Without the hint, it would have been A, left of S on a keyboard, but that is not US/Canada specific

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't thought about left on the keyboard. Maybe US/Canada because some other places use an AZERTY keyboard.