# Where'd you end up? [Part 3!]

Tags: lateral-thinking

> 1. You're in a country which contains thousands of soldiers whom never fight.
> 2. You take the 1st number of the name of this country, and subtract lines of 7.
> 3. Under the square tree's stump.
> 4. You take this number and find a corresponding key.
> 5. You go down soh, left stx and concatenate the first key with this one.
> 6. You are here. What have you made it to?

You can find previous puzzles here:

[Where did you end up? [Part 1]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4299/where-did-you-end-up-part-1)

[Where did you end up? [Part 2!]](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4417/where-did-you-end-up-part-2)

Comment: What do you mean by 'You take the 1st number of the name of this country, and subtract lines of 7'? Is the name a word or a string of digits? When you say 'You go down soh, left stx', what does 'soh' and 'stx' mean?

Comment: SOH and STX are [control characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) in ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is:

> <s>Switzerland (CH)</s> Congo (CD)

Explanation:

> - If the army is the Terracotta Army in China we take the first letter "C" with the 
>    ASCII code of 67.
> - <s>Minus 7 we got 60.</s> The ASCII-code (or 'line number') of "7" is 55.
> - 67 - 55 = 12
> - The square root of <s>60</s> 12 is something like <s>7.74596669241</s> 3.46410161514, but let's round it to 3
> - ASCII code 3 is the ETX(End of Text).
> - SOH (Start of Header) is 1 and STX (Start of Text) is 2.
> - If I look at the ASCII table and go 1 down and 2 right I find the letter <s>"H"</s> "D"
> - concatenate both letters it's CD which is the code for congo

**Edit**:

After reading the comments it should be

> Hawaii (HI)

This is confimred by the OP:

> - The army is the Terracotta Army in China so we take the first letter "C" with the 
>    ASCII code of 67.
> - Minus 3, because a "7" on a digital board has 3 lines
> - The square root of 64 is 8

So the rest of the Explantation could be:

> - the 8th letter on a Keyboard would be the "I"
> - SOH (Start of Header) is 1 and STX (Start of Text) is 2.
> - If we look on the keyboard at the letter "I" and go 1 down and 2 left I find the letter "H"
> - In the comments the OP said "H" woulde be the first letter of the concatenation so it's "HI", which stands for the state Hawaii

Answer (score 1):

A variation of Yvonne's answer:

> Burkina Faso?

Explanation, following the steps of the question:

*1. You're in a country which contains thousands of soldiers who[m] never fight.*

> This is the Terracotta Army, so the country is China.

*2. You take the 1st number of the name of this country, and subtract lines of 7.*

> The first letter of 'China' is 'C', which has ASCII code 67. The number of "lines" in the number 7 printed on a digital board is 3. Subtract 3 from 67 to get 64.

*3. Under the square tree's stump.*

> Take the square root of 64 to get 8.

**everything down to here has been confirmed by the OP**

*4. You take this number and find a corresponding key.*

> The 8th letter key on a (QWERTY) keyboard is 'I'.

*5. You go down soh, left stx and concatenate the first key with this one.*

> SOH (Start of Header) is 1 and STX (Start of Text) is 2, in ASCII code. Start from the I key on your keyboard; go 1 down and 2 left to get to the letter 'G' (or 'H', depending on whether you go down-left or down-right). Concatenate this with the first key to get IG.

*6. You are here. What have you made it to?*

> [The town of Ig, Slovenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ig,_Ig).

Comment: OH MAN THIS IS SO FREAKING CLOSE. Lines of 7. Think hard on that, don't think of it as on paper. Here's a hint; Lines of 1 would be 2, lines of 8 would be 7. :D

Comment: It's 3 lines, @rand. That makes it an even sqrt (64) = 8.

Comment: @warspyking - Have I got it right now?

Comment: @TravisKindred - Thanks! Want to join the fun with [this riddle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/multi-part-challenge-riddles-and-cipher)? :-)

Comment: Wow... You've got up to under the square trees stump (clue 3) finished right! But you've got to find a corresponding key. Don't give up, you're over halfway through! You'll make it. :D

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with BS (backspace)

Comment: @warspyking - So what does 'key' mean? Is it something to do with computers, or music, or what? I'm lost.

Comment: @rand al'thor I used the key to write this comment. Is that a big enough hint for ya?

Comment: @warspyking - Did you use the key exactly 5 times to write that comment? See my updated answer.

Comment: Try the 8th letter key on the keyboard.

Comment: @warspyking - How about now? [wipes sweat from brow]

Comment: H was correct, and H is actually the first letter in the concatenation. After that you're good to go, have a drink of water.